# Show that $K=-\frac{\Delta \log \lambda }{\lambda ^{2}}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $X:\Omega \subset 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{2}\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{3}$ conformal imersion,  $K$ tha a gaussian curvature of an surface $%
S=X\left( \Omega \right) $ in $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{3}$.

Is there an easier way (that does not use the Christoffel symbols) to show the equality below?

$K=-\frac{\Delta \log \lambda }{\lambda ^{2}}$, where $\lambda ^{2}\left( p\right) =\left\Vert X_{u}\right\Vert ^{2}=\left\Vert
X_{v}\right\Vert ^{2}$.

Everywhere I look I just think using the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: If you know how to do surface theory with differential forms, then it's a very easy calculation. Alternatively, since this is an orthogonal chart, you can use the formula $K = -\dfrac1{2\sqrt{EG}}\big(\big(\dfrac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\big)_v + \big(\dfrac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\big)_u\big)$.